# Interpreting kernel message: "page allocation failure. order:1"

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

What is the correct interpretation of the following kernel error message:

```
[N] swapper: page allocation failure. order:1, mode:0x20
[N] Pid: 0, comm: swapper Not tainted 2.6.x #15
```

Is the error fatal (similar to an OOM-kill) or is it just a warning message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the kernel tried to allocate memory (2 pages) and failed.

Whether the error was fatal depends on what component was trying to allocate the memory and if it was a temporary problem or constant one.

Perhaps if you gave us more information (the entire error, system state when it happened, how frequent, etc), you would get a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

It means the kernel tried to allocate memory (2 pages) and failed(copy from @JayM answer)

meaning of second line of the question

in linux kernel sourcetree include/linux/gfp.h

```
 #define ___GFP_HIGH             0x20u
 #define __GFP_HIGH      ((__force gfp_t)___GFP_HIGH)    /* Should access emergency pools? */
```

From my point of view, your server was tight of memory